# Jquery not loading ASP.NET

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I want to start learning jquery/jquery ui but I seem to be stuck at the most basic step; getting it to load. I've tried with 3 different versions and none of them are working.

In my masterpage:

```
<link href="Content/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="Content/css/jquery-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script src="Scripts/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

All of the jquery is from jquery UI download. I've tried with versions from normal jquery site aswell.

When I load page:

[image]

Im trying to run just a simple test in html:

```
<input type="text" name="date" id="date"/>
```

Script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {  
        $("#date").datepicker();
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Have you tried to wrap your code in document ready handler? `$(document).ready(function() { ...  });` As `304 is Not Modified` so not an issue.

Comment: That does not help unfortunately =/

Comment: Are there any javascript errors listed in the `Console`?

Comment: are you sure the path to jquery is correct? `Scripts/jquery.js`

Comment: I drag and drop from my project so the path is correct.

Comment: Try importing jquery with the following: `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Comment: @DelightedD0D, looks like it is correct, otherwise the server would have returned 404 instead of 304 as shown in the screenshot.

Comment: @DelightedD0D Thanks but that did not work either =/

Comment: @DarinDimitrov yup you're right, sorry I missed that

Comment: post your html regarding #date ?, if it has attribute runat="server" then in asp.net  its id gets changed

Comment: @Satindersingh the html is already posted

Comment: Clean up browser cache. Instead of $("#date").datepicker(); try alert(); and check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A page can't be manipulated safely until the document is `ready`. `jQuery` use `$(document).ready()` for this like.

```
<script src="Scripts/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

            $("#date").datepicker();
});  
</script>
```

If it still does not work.. Use

```
  if (typeof jQuery != 'undefined') {

        alert("jQuery library is loaded!");

    }else{

        alert("jQuery library is not found!");

    }
```

to check whether is jQuery is loaded or not. Keep in mind to put this code after where you have loaded the jQuery file.

**Check for jQuery UI**

```
if (typeof jQuery.ui != 'undefined') {
  alert("UI loaded");
}
else alert("UI NOT LOADED");
```

Comment: I get "Jquery library is loaded"

Comment: then use `$(document).ready()` like i have specified above after you load the jQuery file.

Comment: You are doing it after loading `jquery-ui` as well right?

Comment: I thought I did since it was in masterpage but when I move the script sources in to default-page before I run the script it works fine. why is this? Im using doc.ready so shouldnt it wait for it to load?.

Comment: Please add "Add your sources to `header`" in answer. Thanks for help :)

Comment: Check juqery ui is loaded or not? See the updated code